Задача с вычислением ряда на Java
Прошу помочь нубу исправить ошибки. В общем нужно, чтобы программа вычисляла данный ряд

Результат сравнить с

В общем, после помощи в комментариях и исправлений, "родилось" вот это:
package lab1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args){

   System.out.println("Enter x = ");
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   double x = scan.nextDouble();
   double a, s, t, p, eps;
   s=t=x;
   eps=1e-13;
   int i=1;
   p = 2 * i;
   a=1+((x/2)*(Math.sin(x))+((((x*x)/2)-1)*Math.cos(x)));
   System.out.println("Результат формулы = " + a);
   while (Math.abs(t)>eps) {
       t *= (((2*Math.pow(i, 2)) +1) / ((2*i)*((2*i)-1)))*Math.pow(x, p); 
       s += t;
       i++;
   
    System.out.println(s);
    }
    double k = Math.abs(a - s);
    System.out.println("Разница с рядом = " + k);
}
}

Пока оставлю как есть.

Что значит "ничего не вычисляется"? Программа висит? Программа выдаёт не те результаты? Какие именно она выдаёт? А какие должна? Какое число x вы вводите? Попробуйте печатать значения t и s внутри цикла на каждом шаге, возможно сразу что-то станет более понятно. Я, кстати, не вижу здесь никакого "ряда". Здесь только формула вычисления значения некоей функции от x. Где собственно ряд то? В коде у вас есть умножение и сложение членов ряда, но в формуле на картинке этого ничего нет.

Программа просто не выдает результат, пишешь любую цифру после "Enter x = " , жмешь "enter" и курсор просто переходит на следующую строку без вывода результата.

Уже чуть понятнее. Программа просто висит, гоняя бесконечно цикл while. Ответьте и на остальные вопросы: какое значение x вы вводите и что собственно за ряд вы считаете? И как минимум вы очень странно инициализируете ваши переменные. Очень сомневаюсь, что начальные значения s и t должны равняться x.

Ага, ну как я и думал. Синус и косинус - это формула для проверки результата ваших вычислений. А сам ряд считается по другой формуле. Переписывайте ваш код, чтобы он соответствовал формуле. Подумайте, как вычислить i-й член ряда и чему первоначально должна равняться сумма ряда. И тут у вас по-простому не получится i+1 член ряда вычислить через i-й. Ну, вернее, можно подумать, как оптимизировать, но это потом.

Добавил в развернутом виде формулу ряда. Ввожу любую цифру, например, 1, 3, 7 и т. п. Преподаватель показывал пример с такой инициализацией переменных.

Ну, я вам уже всё ответил выше. Читайте, думайте, делайте.

Кажется понял, тут надо использовать (((2ii) +1)/((2i)!))(x^(i*i)), вместо того, что я написал, а вставленная формула, получается, просто проверка результата, которую отдельным выводом в консоль нужно реализовать?

Да, всё именно так

Почему не написал проверку результата?

Вы забыли домножить на степень X, и Вычисление a вынесите из цикла

Точно, сейчас поправлю.

И посмотрите, как сделано в ответе - большие степени и факториалы не рассчитываются, имеющаяся дробь обновляется, это и быстрее, и точнее.

предложенный ответ даёт результат, который отличается от a ровно на x - возможно, в формуле икса не хватает, или специально так сделано.

То есть разница  в результате - это не ошибка?

"родилось" вот это — улыбнуло) Сколько же у вас правок! Вы не думали сделать вопрос общим?)) А если серьёзно, то удалите этот код из вопроса и оформите свой ответ (желательно с указанием лиц, которые вам помогли в комментариях). Но вы уже приняли ответ  Так что либо просто удалите код, либо оформите как собственный ответ (как альтернативу принятому)

У вас ОЧЕНЬ много изменений. Вот как было бы хорошо поступить — откатить вопрос, оставив нерабочий код, но дополнив вопрос подробностями (из комментариев), а затем добавить свой собственный ответ с рабочим кодом

К сожалению исходника не сохранил, правил и копировал что получилось все из "эклипса".  Собственно, как и заданный вопрос, "джаву" увидел в глаза неделю назад, поэтому не знаком с ее синтаксисом и не могу понять, правильно ли у меня выдает результат по заданию или нет. Вопрост также уже закрыли, видимо за это, потому и дать свой ответ не могу.

На сайте есть своего рода система контроля версии текста (редакции — находится сверху от окна заголовка вопроса в режиме править). Ваш изначальный код содержится в версии редакции от 23 окт. в 15:14. Да, ваш вопрос закрыт, но он не будет удалён, поскольку вы приняли ответ. У вас есть возможность редактировать даже закрытые вопросы :)

Но тогда вы не откатывайте вопрос, а замените текущий код тем, что был в версии от 23 окт. в 15:14 (надеюсь не сложно объяснил...) И для того, чтобы кто-то конкретный увидел адресованное вами сообщения, пишите в начале текста @ и дальше ник того, кого хотите упомянуть

@Maxim, вот так происходит упоминание людей. Автор вопроса/ответа всегда получает упоминания даже без спецсимвола. Спецсимвол нужен для сторонних людей (кто оставлял свой комментарий под вопросом/ответом)

@Chaos_Sower, спасибо, теперь буду иметь в виду! Где достать исходник разобрался, только смысл?

Пожалуйста! :) А смысл, Максим, в том, чтобы другие люди с похожей проблемой могли воспользоваться вашим вопросом и ответом под ним. А то получается, что ваш код кое-как починен, и смысл вопроса пропадает. А так у вас в вопросе хоть и будет неработающий код (но будут подробности описанной вами проблемы), зато ответ другого человека как раз таки его "починит". Таким образом получится сбалансировать и вопрос, и ответ. Так и работает Stack Overflow =)

Ну в комментариях вроде разобрались, что сам ряд сейчас на первой картинке, а результат должен быть равен вычисленному по формуле на второй картинке.
Для разумного вычисления удобно отдельно модифицировать часть над дробной чертой и отдельно x^(2i)/(2i)!, примерно так:
i = 0;
mx2 = -x*x;
a = 1.0;
b = -1.0; 
while (Math.abs(t)>eps) {
   i++;
   a += 4 * i - 2;
   b *= mx2 / (2*i*(2*i-1)) 
   t = a * b;
   s += t;
}
   


Цикл while можно заменить на for
